# Print json response as array with key and value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I need to print the json response in 'resulte' div as array same as that was sent by php.

**Upload.php:**

```
$arr=array('username'=>array('isEmpty'=>'required','exists'=>'username exists'),'password'=>array('isEmpty'=>'requiredd'));
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**index.php:**

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function a(){
    $('#submitForm').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
document.getElementById('resulte').innerHTML=”I need to print the response array here like key=>value”;
                }}).submit();
         }
</script>

    <form id="submitForm" name="submitForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    File: <input name="myfile" type="file" />
    <input type="button" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" onclick="a();" />
    </form>
<div id="resulte" name="resulte"></div>
```

suppose I don’t know the keys and values and how many record is received in index.php. so I would like to use some condition here like :

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
if($key==” username”){
echo $key.”=><br />”;
      foreach($value as $k=>$val){
          if($k==” isEmpty”){
             echo $k.”=>”.$val.”<br />”;
}
 }
  }
}
```

how can I do all those by javascript ?

-thanks.

**RESOLVED:**

(According to the answer of 'josh')

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function a(){
    $('#submitForm').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
for (var key in result) {
  if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if(key == "username") {
        document.getElementById('resulte').innerHTML = key + " => <br />";
        for (var k in result[key]) {
          if (k == "isEmpty") {
            document.getElementById('resulte').innerHTML += k + " => " + result[key][k] + "<br />";
          }
        }
    }
  }
}     
                }}).submit();
         }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var p = {"username":{"isEmpty":"required","exists":"username exists"},"password":{"isEmpty":"requiredd"}};

for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if(key == "username") {
        document.getElementById('resulte').innerHTML += key + " -> " + p[key] + "<br />";
        for (var k in p[key]) {
          if (k == "isEmpty") {
            document.getElementById('resulte').innerHTML += k + " -> " + p[key][k] + "<br />";
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I got this output "username -> [object Object]"

Comment: please see my update, if you make correction of your answer then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I edited the code. You're getting `username -> [object Object]` because the value is an array, which is an object. You can take out that line and change the conditions to fit your needs.

Comment: thanks for edit, now I can accept the answer. yeah I already did that ("RESOLVED" part of my question)